# Compact Manifold Realized as One-Point Compactification

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness, compactification

I'm working on the following Problem from Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*:

"Let $M$ be a compact manifold of positive dimension, and let $p \in M$. Show that $M$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $M \setminus \{p\}$."

I came up with a proof, but it didn't use the fact that $M$ has positive dimension; in fact, I think the statement is still true when $M$ has dimension $0$. Is that the case? And if so, why did the author specify positive dimension in the problem? Is it to signal that the result is trivial in the $0$-dimensional case?

Comment: If $M$ is compact and zero-dimensional, then it is a finite set of points. Consequently $M\setminus\{p\}$ is already compact for any $p\in M$. You can define the one-point `compactification' for compact space by taking a disjoint union with an external point, and in this case Lee's statement remains valid in the 0-dimensional case. The terminology is somewhat incorrect, however.

Comment: @Tyrone your comment looks like an answer to me.